# Using Scanf for Storing Input in 2d Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, scanf, multidimensional-array

I want to scan input and save it in a square 2d array.

The first two digits are saved in seperate variables, the first digit is a target number (irrelevant here), the second digit gets saved in variable **m**, i.e. **m** = 5 in this case. **m** is the number of rows/colums of the square matrix. The rest of the input should be saved in the array.
For this particular input, I get a segmentation-fault and random numbers are printed on the screen.
I used some printf statements to trace where things go wrong, and I noticed that the index **i** in the first loop jumped from 2 to 11 in one scenario, for other input it jumped to 33.
Thanks for your help! I hope I am not missing an obvious mistake.

Input: (each row is seperated by the previous by pressing enter.)

> 42 5
>
> 0 3 7 9 10
>
> 9 13 20 5 20
>
> 12 11 33 0 12
>
> 17 39 22 3 18

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* arv[]){

  int target;               // for later processing, irrelevant here
  int m;                    // m = #rows and #columns of array
  int array[m][m];
  scanf("%d %d", &target, &m);
 
  int i, k;
  for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(k = 0; k < m; k++){
       scanf("%d", &(array[i][k]));    // save value in array.
    }
  }
                                      // the problem occurs before this point.
  for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
     for(k = 0; k < m; k++){
       printf("%2d", array[i][k]);    // print array.
     }
     printf("\n");
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declare your array of variable length `m` before `m` has a meaningful value. Put that declaration after the first `scanf`.

Comment: @MOehm I can't believe I just spent two hours trying to find out what is wrong and missing that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, the proverbial fresh set of eyes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized the value of `m` before creating `array[m][m]`. Without initializing, the value of `m` can be anything.

Change:

```
int array[m][m];
scanf("%d %d", &target, &m);
```

to

```
scanf("%d %d", &target, &m);
int array[m][m];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the place where you messed up.

```
int m;
int array[m][m];
```

Here ,`m` is uninitialized and you are creating an array of `m*m` elements. You need `m` initialized before the declaration of the array. So move the array declaration after the `scanf` just after it so that `m` gets initialized before you declare the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#innclude <stdio.h>

int i, j;
int t[5][5];
i=0;
j=0;

while(i < 5)
{
    j = 0;
    while (j < 5)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(t[i][j++]));
    }
    i++;
}
```